# Implement Radau-IIA-method

Tags: matlab, runge-kutta

I´m looking for an implementation of the Radau-IIA-method with order 3 in MATLAB to solve a DAE system. This is my system (Rober problem):

```
y1'=-0.04*y1+10^4*y2*y3
y2'= 0.04*y1-10^4*y2*y3-3*10^7*y2^2
0=y1+y2+y3-1
```

Initial values are

```
y1(0)=1 and y2(0)=y3(0)=0.
```

The Runge-Kutta tableau looks like this

```
1/3  |  5/12  -1/12
1    |  3/4    1/4
_____|_______________
     |  3/4    1/4
```

(Sorry, I don´t know if there is a possibility to write LaTeX or something in StackOverflow).

I have no idea how to do that..

Comment: Are you sure that that's a DAE system? Where is the algebraic part? There are explicit first derivatives for all function/dependent variables.

Comment: For a description of the stiff ODE system, expected solutions and failure sources see http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/vodef90web/problems/demosnodislin/Single/DemoRobertson/demorobertson.pdf -- Perhaps this problem should be migrated to math.stackexchange.com, since it is less about the scripting of a present algorithm but more about the design of this algorithm. There you also have LaTeX support.

Comment: You will need to implement a Newton method or some other solver for nonlinear systems.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the third equation so now it is a DAE system.

Comment: A bit late, but a Matlab implementation of Radau IIA can be found [on FileExchange](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56162-radau-iia).